# How can i rewrite my typescript code so that it wont trigger http request?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hi I am having angular UI . I have formcontrol named range . range basically is an array for two moment objects ( something like this [ moment(),moment() ].  when the user clicks a clear button from the UI the range is cleared and set to null. when range is null i dont want to trigger the http call (campaignsService.getUnpaginatedCampaignsWithinRange) . how can i do it . the following is my code snippet. In other words if this.rangeControl.value[0] or this.rangeControl.value[1] or "value" is equal to null i dont want to trigger calling the  method this.campaignsService.getUnpaginatedCampaignsWithinRange

```
 if(!this.isGlobalAdmin){
  this.rangeControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap( value =>  this.campaignsService.getUnpaginatedCampaignsWithinRange(
      { 
        accountIds : this.currentUserAccount? this.currentUserAccount.id: null,
        campaignStatuses: this.campaignStatusIds,
        rangeStartDate: (this.rangeControl.value[0]).toISOString(),
        rangeEndDate: (this.rangeControl.value[1]).toISOString()
      }
    )
  ),
  tap((campaigns) => { this.campaigns = campaigns; })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

really appreciate any help

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, Just filter your value change. Add filter and pass condition as per your requirement.

RxJS filter is used to filter values emitted by source Observable on the basis of given predicate. If the condition returns true, filter will emit value obtained from source Observable otherwise not.

> filter(x => x !== null),

```
if(!this.isGlobalAdmin){
  this.rangeControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(x => x !== null), // add filter and pass condition as per your requirement
    switchMap( value =>  this.campaignsService.getUnpaginatedCampaignsWithinRange(
      { 
        accountIds : this.currentUserAccount? this.currentUserAccount.id: null,
        campaignStatuses: this.campaignStatusIds,
        rangeStartDate: (this.rangeControl.value[0]).toISOString(),
        rangeEndDate: (this.rangeControl.value[1]).toISOString()
      }
    )
  ),
  tap((campaigns) => { this.campaigns = campaigns; })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Refer this for RxjS Filter: https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-rxjs-filter